# Ball animation using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I did a animation using `javascript`. Using single ball shape goes top of the page. Anybody would help how to create multiple balls like clone.. I just want the following tasks..

- Animation with multiple balls **(Bottom to top)**
- Each ball position **(Left position only)** is random.
- Infinite process.

Is it possible to achieve through `javascript`. Thanks in advance :)

```css
.circle{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -60px;
    left: 2px;
    transition: 0.1s;
}
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background: violet
}
#box{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  
  <div id="box"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green', 'brown', 'violet'];
var windowHeight = 0;
var parendElement;
window.onload = function () {
    parendElement = document.getElementById("box");
    windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    document.body.style.height = windowHeight + "px";
    console.log(document.body.style.height);
    generateBall();
};
function generateBall() {
    
    var leftPos = Math.floor((Math.random() * window.innerWidth) - 30);
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    para.setAttribute("class", 'circle');
    para.style.background = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    para.style.left = leftPos + "px";
    parendElement.appendChild(para);
    var btmPos = 0;
    var animationInterval = setInterval(function () {
        if (btmPos < windowHeight) {
            btmPos += 5;
        } else {
            console.log("yes");
            clearInterval(animationInterval);
            parendElement.removeChild(para);
        }
        para.style.bottom = btmPos + "px";
        para.style.left = leftPos + "px";
    }, 100);
}
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: With regards to your tasks, what have you tried? If you don't know where to start, list your thought process on the matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might help you..

```js
var canvas = {
    element: document.getElementById('canvas'),
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    initialize: function () {
        this.element.style.width = this.width + 'px';
        this.element.style.height = this.height + 'px';
        document.body.appendChild(this.element);
    }
};

var Ball = {
    create: function (color, dx, dy) {
        var newBall = Object.create(this);
        newBall.dx = dx;
        newBall.dy = dy;
        newBall.width = 40;
        newBall.height = 40;
        newBall.element = document.createElement('div');
        newBall.element.style.backgroundColor = color;
        newBall.element.style.width = newBall.width + 'px';
        newBall.element.style.height = newBall.height + 'px';
        newBall.element.className += ' ball';
        newBall.width = parseInt(newBall.element.style.width);
        newBall.height = parseInt(newBall.element.style.height);
        canvas.element.appendChild(newBall.element);
        return newBall;
    },
    moveTo: function (x, y) {
        this.element.style.left = x + 'px';
        this.element.style.top = y + 'px';
    },
    changeDirectionIfNecessary: function (x, y) {
        if (x < 0 || x > canvas.width - this.width) {
            this.dx = -this.dx;
        }
        if (y < 0 || y > canvas.height - this.height) {
            this.dy = -this.dy;
        }
    },
    draw: function (x, y) {
        this.moveTo(x, y);
        var ball = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            ball.changeDirectionIfNecessary(x, y);
            ball.draw(x + ball.dx, y + ball.dy);
        }, 1000 / 60);
    }
};

canvas.initialize();
var ball1 =  Ball.create("blue", 4, 3);
var ball2 =  Ball.create("red", 1, 5);
var ball3 =  Ball.create("green", 2, 2);
ball1.draw(70, 0);
ball2.draw(20, 200);
ball3.draw(300, 330);
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}
#canvas {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ccddcc;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
.ball {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Bouncing Balls</h1>

<p>These bouncing balls are made with completely raw JavaScript,
    just with divs. We don't use jQuery. We don't use canvas.</p>

<div id="canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add this code
`var interval = setInterval(function () {
        generateBall();
    }, 1000);`

into your `window.onload()`. It works :) ..

```css
.circle{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -60px;
    left: 2px;
    transition: 0.1s;
}
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background: violet
}
#box{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  
  <div id="box"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green', 'brown', 'violet'];
var windowHeight = 0;
var parendElement;
window.onload = function () {
    parendElement = document.getElementById("box");
    windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    document.body.style.height = windowHeight + "px";
    console.log(document.body.style.height);
    generateBall();
  
    //Creates ball for every 1 second interval
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        generateBall();
    }, 1000);
};
function generateBall() {
    
    var leftPos = Math.floor((Math.random() * window.innerWidth) - 30);
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    para.setAttribute("class", 'circle');
    para.style.background = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    para.style.left = leftPos + "px";
    parendElement.appendChild(para);
    var btmPos = 0;
    var animationInterval = setInterval(function () {
        if (btmPos < windowHeight) {
            btmPos += 5;
        } else {
            console.log("yes");
            clearInterval(animationInterval);
            parendElement.removeChild(para);
        }
        para.style.bottom = btmPos + "px";
        para.style.left = leftPos + "px";
    }, 100);
}
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Perfect.. Thanks :)